# Universal image quality index wrong result

Tags: image, matlab

Below is an algorithm for `UNIVERSAL IMAGE QUALITY INDEX`:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

img2 = rgb2gray(imread('No_Noise.png')); 
img2 = imnoise(ref,'salt & pepper',1); % Noisy image

img1 = imgaussfilt(img2, 2); % Filtered noisy image

quality = imageQualityIndex(img1, img2)
```

Universal image quality index (Q-index) has it's boundaries between -1 and +1. But in this particular case the result is `1.0007`. Yes, it's only a little bit above it's boundaries, but still it is wrong.

`imageQualityIndex` is a downloaded function from:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29500-image-error-measurements

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You're asking us to debug someone else's code? Why don't you ask the author?

Comment: I asked in different cases an author many times, never got a response.